# apache echart with one month each year

Tags: echarts

Hello,
I am trying to make a line type chart.
With in axis a date in the format of one month over several years.
Ex July 2000, July 2001, July 2002 etc.

I have a data array with a [date, value] couple.
So with the example it gives

```
{
    series: [{
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [
            [ {value: ['2000-07-01', 5884] } ],
            [ {value: ['2001-07-01', 568] } ],
            [ {value: ['2002-07-01', 5845884] } ]
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        smooth: true,
        data: [
            [ {value: ['2000-07-01', 458] } ],
            [ {value: ['2001-07-01', 5468] } ],
            [ {value: ['2002-07-01', 588484] } ]
        ]
    }]
}
```

and I defined in the x axis

```
{
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: (function(value){
                return moment(value).format('MMM YYYY');
            })
        },
    },
 }
```

But on the x axis I get [August 2000, September 2001, October 2002]

How can I obtain the requested result?
Do I have to reformat my series and put my dates in the x axis label?
thx for help.

Answer (score 2):

The required result can be obtained using category axis, if you can provide the data for all months without gap.

`xAxis.axisLabel.interval` property allows you to control the interval between the labels displayed.

Refer the chart configuration below,

```
option = {
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    axisLabel: {
        formatter: (function(value){
            //return mement(value).format('MMM YYYY');
            return echarts.format.formatTime("MM-yyyy", value);
        }),
        interval: 0
    },
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
},
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    smooth: true,
    data: [
        ['2000-07-01', 5884],
        ['2001-07-01', 568],
        ['2002-07-01', 5845884] 
    ]
}, {
    type: 'line',
    smooth: true,
    data: [
        ['2000-07-01', 458],
        ['2001-07-01', 5468],
        ['2002-07-01', 588484] 
    ]
}]
```

};

[image: Echarts with all axis labels displayed]